# What is an "active thread" in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

From [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360030/), there are two opinions of what [Thread#activeCount()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) returns.

1. An "active thread" is actually executing bytecode. It is a thread that was started and is not waiting on IO or on a lock.
2. An "active thread" is in the `run()` method. I.e., a nonactive thread has not started the `run()` method or has exited that method.

What is the actual meaning?

(I ask on Software Engineering as StackOverflow disfavors such explanation questions.)

Comment: I don't know if this is a special term in Java programming, but an _active thread_ is one that is currently scheduled to be executed at a CPU core from my understanding.

Comment: Also: Aren't the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360030/what-defines-an-active-thread) satisfying?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  "Aren't the answers here satisfying?" I linked to that SO page in my question. The answers there are quite inconclusive, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  What do you mean  by "currently scheduled to be executed at a CPU core"? Do you mean "actually  running on the CPU"? If a thread is just waiting for CPU time, is it active? What if it is blocked on IO or on an object lock?

Answer (score 3):

From the JavaDoc's for this method:

> Returns an estimate of the number of active threads in the current thread's thread group and its subgroups. Recursively iterates over all subgroups in the current thread's thread group.
>
> The value returned is only an estimate because the number of threads may change dynamically while this method traverses internal data structures, and might be affected by the presence of certain system threads. This method is intended primarily for debugging and monitoring purposes.

Looking at the code in ThreadGroup for this, I gather that it is based upon the value of the `nthreads` variable of ThreadGroup which is incremented when the `add(Thread)` method is called (created) and decremented when the `remove(Thread)` method is called.

The `add` method is called when a thread is created.  The `remove` method is called when a thread is terminated or fails to start.  That is, a thread that has not yet started is counted but if it subsequently fails when started, it will no longer be counted.

Comment: Thank you. So, a thread is active from the moment that the constructor Thread() is called. A thread then becomes  nonactive if and only if it has exited. Is that right? OK, but if so, then this part of the Java thread API seems  of little use . What I would naturally want to know is #1 in my question.

Do you know of an  article that discusses this?

Comment: @JoshuaFox: The answer is in the source code, as Jimmy already explained.

Comment: And knowing whether an "active" thread is actively executing instructions or not doesn't seem all that interesting to me.  Threads are an abstraction; you're not supposed to have to know about how the operating system is managing them.  If you want to know those kinds of details, you could probably use a profiler to see how much time the processor is spending in each thread.

Comment: @JoshuaFox I'm not sure I understand completely.  You want to know at a given moment, how many threads doing work?  By that do you mean they are using CPU?

Comment: @JoshuaFox You could loop through the threads and get the states to find which ones are `RUNNABLE`.  The challenge is that by the time you check the state of last one, the state of the others could change.

Comment: @JimmyJames I don't know how IO-bound vs  CPU-bound my application is. It would be nice to know how many threads are not blocked on IO (etc.) and so are "active".

Comment: " find which ones are RUNNABLE " --  Interesting option. Could be useful. "...  could change" I am not too bothered if my numbers are somewhat inaccurate. But I appreciate that all this is nonstandard and so I will have to consider it carefully before doing it.

Comment: @JoshuaFox It sounds like a statistical solution might work.  Perhaps sampling at a roughly consistent interval.

Comment: @JoshuaFox Actually, you might want to try random sampling.  If there's a rhythm to the application, consistent sampling might give you misleading results.  I would try both.

Comment: @JimmyJames makes sense. I wonder if there is some open-source for this

Answer (score -1):

As in the java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)  :
Thread states:

- BLOCKED : Thread state for a thread blocked waiting for a monitor
  lock.
- NEW : Thread state for a thread which has not yet started.
- RUNNABLE : Thread state for a runnable thread.
- TERMINATED : Thread    state for a terminated thread.
- TIMED_WAITING : Thread state for a    waiting thread with a specified
  waiting time.
- WAITING : Thread state    for a waiting thread.

So active depend on context and usually it refer to your second interpretation.

Comment: Thank you. But I do not see the word "Active" on that page. How do you reach your conclusion?

Comment: Exactly, there is no active state in the returned states.

Comment: please explain. If there is "no active state in the returned states", then what *is* an active state?

Comment: Appreciating if you explain more the context of the term.

Comment: "... the context of the term". I would like to understand the method Thread#activeCount. Link  in question

Comment: This isnt really answering the question.